# Подключить свой js файл к чужому сайту

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Есть некий сайт. Работаю с ним в консоли (В образовательных целях). Можно ли как-то упростить этот процесс? Скажем, работать в отдельном файле, а в консоли просто его подключить? Может есть способы проще?

Браузер Хром.

Answer (score 4):

Да, есть варианты.

1. В Chrome нужно открыть инструменты разработчика (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+I</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> или в меню браузера **Дополнительные инструменты** -> **Инструменты разработчика**). Далее, в открывшемся окне, нужно выбрать вкладку **Source**. На этой вкладке в левой панели **Navigator** нужно открыть вкладку **Snippets** и писать свой код там. Для запуска нужно нажать <kbd>Ctrl+Enter</kbd>;

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Использовать расширение [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).